# docker push - access not authorized

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I am trying to push an image to docker hub.

I created an account "kaffeekaethe" and created a public repository "reservierung".

I build the image "kaffeekaethe/reservierung" (no typos, I double checked that).

Afterwards I logged into docker hub and tried to push the image, but I am alwasy getting the error "access to the requested resource is not authorized". Everyone else who had this problem wasn't logged in prior to the push command, and that was the only solution that I've found. Is there any other reason for this error?

Comment: What system are you running docker on locally? There have been / are some issues when trying to push from a windows host to a linux registry, that may be related. Also which version of docker are you running (`docker version`)

Comment: Yes, I am running it from windows.

My Version is:
Client:
Version: 1.9.0, OS/Arch: windows/amd64

Server:
Version: 1.10.1, OS/Arch: linux/amd64

Comment: Looks like you have an older client installed; can you try installing the latest version of docker toolbox? Docker 1.10 (which is included in that version) fixes various issues with authenticating to Docker Hub on Windows